# Angular - Twitter Direct Message with window object not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, angular

I want to compose a Twitter DM with pre-populated text. Currently, I am using window.open() to compose the message.

window.open(`https://twitter.com/messages/compose?text=${this.helloWorld}`);

> helloWorld = "test test"

It is working fine on the windows and android but I'm not able to get the pre-populated text on the iPhone.

Here is the code:

```css
handleSocialClick(){ window.open(https://twitter.com/messages/compose?text=${this.helloWorld}) }
```

```html
<a (click)="handleSocialClick()" [ngClass]="socialOption.panelClass"> 
    <i [ngClass]="socialOption.icon"></i> {{socialOption.name}} </a>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested below?

Comment: @iLuvLogix, I have an anchor link with a click event that calls a function, and that function simply uses the URL in string format. Not using any service to load the URL. Here is how I am building the URL: 'twitter-compose-url' + {param}

on Safari, everything works well except the prepopulated text.

Comment: Can you provide the full code-snippet with the func and the prepopulations? Just paste it in your question..

Comment: <a (click)="handleSocialClick()" [ngClass]="socialOption.panelClass">
  <i [ngClass]="socialOption.icon"></i>
   {{socialOption.name}}
</a>

handleSocialClick(){
window.open(`https://twitter.com/messages/compose?text=${this.helloWorld}`)
}

Answer (score 1):

You can't safely rely on `window.open` due to variations in browsers policies.

In order to make `window.open()` work in safari on iOS you can place it in an element's `onclick` attribute.

Here's an example with a button, but you can place an `onclick` event on whatever container-element you are using:

```
<button class='button' onclick='window.open("https://twitter.com/messages/compose?text=${this.helloWorld}", "_blank");'>Twitter Message</button>
```

In case you are using async calls to retrieve your urls - keep in mind: Safari blocks calls to `window.open()` made inside async calls. The workaround is to call `window.open` before the asnyc call and set the location after the promise was resolved.

Example:

```
var myWindowRef = window.open();

someService.getUrl().then(function(url) {
     myWindowRef .location = url;
});
```

In regards to your specific situations:

in yourcomponent.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})


export class AppComponent  {
  ...
  ..
  helloWorld = 'Hello World';
  handleSocialClick(){ 
   window.open(`https://twitter.com/messages/compose?text=${this.helloWorld}`) 
 }

}
```

in yourcomponent.html:

```
...
..
<a (click)="handleSocialClick()" [ngClass]="socialOption.panelClass"> 
    <i [ngClass]="socialOption.icon"></i> {{socialOption.name}} </a> 
...
..
```

Comment: Yes. quite similar

Comment: @DipakKumarSingh Remind me again - what part isn't working atm?